# still experiencing linker error despite linking the java jar file in visual studio code

Tags: java, opencv, visual-studio-code

I am trying to build a small personal project with opencv. I included the path to the opencv jar file in visual studio using the java dependencies then referenced libraries but i get the linker error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java430 in java.library.path. I have no idea what else i could do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UnsatisfiedLinkError isn't about jar files.

It's about 'native' files. These are generally stored as a `.jnilib` file on mac, as a `.DLL` on windows, and as a `.so` file on on most unixen.

They cannot be in jar files.

Some libraries will put in some effort and ship a whole bevy of them (as each architecture and OS has a unique dll/jnilib/so file that is needed) inside the jar, will find the 'right' one for your arch/os combo, unpack it someplace, and try to load it live.

This is either not working, or this library isn't doing that. Presumably the opencv site contains a tutorial on how to get it running; as native files are required, it's a bit more involved than 'just download, add to classpath, and voila'. I suggest you follow it precisely.

If you do have something that seems suitable (probably called opencv_java430.dll or whatnot), start java with `java -Djava.library.path=/directory/containing/that/file the.rest.of.your.java.args` - that should help.